Simulating pump.fun swap transaction on solana
Is simulating pump.fun buy instruction possible?
So basically when I simulate transaction it doesnt work but when i create transaction signature and confirm   it buys the coin without any problem.
main.py:
from solders.pubkey import Pubkey

from pumpfun.pumpfun import buy


buy(Pubkey.from_string('token_mint_string'), 0.05)


pumpfun.py:
    def buy(token_mint_address: Pubkey, sol_buy_amount: float):
        # ... (some code that is not that important)
        compiled_message: MessageV0 = MessageV0.try_compile(
            payer=owner_pubkey,
            instructions=instructions,
            address_lookup_table_accounts=[],
            recent_blockhash=client.get_latest_blockhash().value.blockhash,
        )

        transaction: VersionedTransaction = VersionedTransaction(compiled_message, [payer_keypair])

        print(client.simulate_transaction(transaction))

OUTPUT: 
SimulateTransactionResp { context: RpcResponseContext { slot: 277011621, api_version: Some("1.18.15") }, value: RpcSimulateTransactionResult(RpcSimulateTransactionResult { err: Some(AccountNotFound), logs: Some([]), accounts: None, units_consumed: Some(0), return_data: None, inner_instructions: None }) }

err: Some(AccountNotFound).
I know it's the right contact address (mint).
Do I need to have funds on the account to simulate transactions?

So basically you need some funds on the wallet to simulate transaction. it took around 0.00014 solanas in my case. (based on compute budget limit and price)
